# printf wrong output when reversing a string

Tags: c, string, pointers, printf, reverse

so this is the code for reversing a string

```
#include<stdio.h>

char* function(char *);
int main()
{   
   char a[]="computer";
   printf("%s", function(a));
   return 0;
}

char* function(char *p)
{
   int l,i;
   char t;
   for (l=0;*(p+l)!='\0';l++);
   for(i=0; i<(l/2) ; i++)
    {
        t=*(p+i);
        *(p+i)=*(p+l-1-i);
        *(p+l-1-i)=t;
    }

   return (p);
}
```

but if i change `printf("%s", function(a));` in the main body to

```
printf("%s", function("computer"));
```

there is no output (the output is blank) in dev c++.... but it gives the desired output in turbo c++ even with this change....why is that?

Comment: Your program invokes undefined behavior when you write to a string literal with the second version. There are at least a thousand duplicates of this issue on this site, but the title's rarely reflect the actual issue, and are so divergent they're surprisingly difficult to find. Turbo C++ is probably older than *you* are, so get a modern compiler and turn up your warnings to pedantic levels.

Comment: *Exact* duplicate of [Reversing a string literal in C with pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43350179/2564301)

Comment: Tip: Don't use `l` and `1` and `i` in arithmetic expressions.

Comment: @TimRandall because we can get it mixed up right?

Comment: @AnasAziz Yes, it's difficult to read. Personally I don't like to use single letter variable names, except in `for` loops or cases where the meaning is super-obvious. I like to use one or two word names where possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameter `"computer"`, which you pass to `function`, is a string literal, and changing/manipulating the contents of a string literal is undefined behaviour. That's what you are experiencing - something undefined.

Comment: but then why is it running OK in turboC++ ide?

Comment: @Anas: because software from the 1980s did not check if the programmer followed the syntax rules. It just expected them to.